# How to import parent-to-child relationships into CSV via Apex?

Tags: apex

I made an apex script that backups any object (selected by the user via custom lwc) in the SFDC org, and stores it into SFDC internal file storage as a CSV file. The CSV is made via apex code.

I did all of this because, when I need, I can rollback my db restoring the CSV file.

Here comes the problem: I make the backup (CSV) of the db in a given time; now after I've done the backup, let's suppose I update some records, I understand that I messed up, and I restore the backup; all good since, after the backup, I only did some *updates* on the records of a given object (suppose Account), so when I rollback via CSV the ids of the Accounts will be the same.

In the scenario where, after the backup, I delete 10 accounts, when I restore via CSV, it will be an INSERT for salesforce, so the 10 accounts that I will restore, now will have new ids. So here comes my question: How can I maintain the relationships between objects in the scenario where I will have new ids for the "older" accounts? Is there a way to implement a dynamic logic? Am I missing something?

P.S. Ii need to do it via apex code, can't use dataloader or other tool, can't create an external ID field on the object UNLESS it is done via Apex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So here comes my question: How can i mantain the relationships between
> objects in the scenario where i will have new ids for the "older"
> accounts? Is there a way to implement a dynamic logic? Am i missing
> something?

I'm assuming here that you are neither backing up a large volume of data nor maintaining it for a longer duration (because if you did then your solution is not really a scalable one). So, for a small volume of data (if the backup duration is less than 15 days), you can actually restore the deleted records from recycle bin (instead of restoring based on the data from CSV and the CSV would merely be for reference/ quick check purposes). This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=recycle_bin_considerations.htm&type=5) would be a good starting point for further brainstorming.

If you really prefer using CSV file for backing up the records, then you need to back up the related records as well and write apex code to update the relationship records after restore. This can be anywhere between easy to really difficult depending on your data schema and requirements.

If you need to back up large volume of data or maintain it for longer duration, then its better to invest in data backup and restore apps (quite a few apps are available in the app store) at some cost.

---

**Update:**

If you want to back up large volume of data and maintain it for a longer duration and do not want to invest in apps that cost, then maintaining CSV backup may not be a scalable approach.

- Consider storing the data in another DB (like postgres on Heroku) where you might be able to replicate exact (or almost similar) DB schema as your SF org. This way you could maintain the data relationships as-is and make it easier for restoration. You can develop custom apex integration logic that would export the data or import the data. Trailhead modules ([this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services) & [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce_heroku_integration)) would be a good starting point to get a high level overview, if you have not looked at these already. You will have the flexibility of using REST or SOAP services, if needed in this approach but may required some additional UI component development.
- If you want to maintain CSV back up in network drives, consider using batch apex or bulk API because they are meant for large volume data handling, but maintaining a relational data back-up is going to be a big challenge for you. You could also write scripts that would automate triggering data import/ export via data loader tool (I've not personally done this script, but shouldn't be too difficult to figure it out).
- Regardless of the approach you are going to take, this series of articles ([Part1](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2015/03/salesforce-backup-and-restore-essentials-part-1-backup-overview-api-options-and-performance.html), [Part2](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2015/06/salesforce-backup-and-restore-essentials-part-2-restore-strategies-and-processes.html), [Part3](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2016/02/salesforce-backup-restore-essentials-part-3-learn-customers-experience.html), [Part4](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2016/09/salesforce-backup-restore-essentials-part-4-minimize-transformation-restoring-data.html)) is a must read for you to get a good grasp on some of the problems you might encounter (esp., part 2 & 4). Also, though not a must, consider reading [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/02/extreme-salesforce-data-loading-part-1-tune-your-data-model.html) & [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/extreme-force-com-data-loading-part-3-suspending-events-that-fire-on-insert.html).

Comment: My goal was to "create" the same functionalities as backup and restore apps, but i would like to do it myself; Thought about the recycle bin, but 15 days is a limit i want to avoid, and i need to store a large amount of data and mantain for longer duration. So other than apps, what would be a good solution? I'm open to remake also the logic

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to create a replica of the DB schema on another DB and export/ import the data via integration. This way querying the relational data on the external DB becomes a lot easier and so will be the restore. While the deep dive details of this approach are beyond the scope here, I've updated my answer with some more details and articles you should look into. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was also thinking about Database.SaveResult class. If i do an insert with Database.insert, after i can get, via SaveResult, the IDs of the inserted objects. Now the question is: is the insert order guarranted? eg i create a list of 10 accounts, from acc0 to acc9; when i do the insert, will SFDC insert the accounts in order (from acc0 to acc9) or the order is not guaranteed? I found this:
"Each element in the SaveResult array corresponds to the sObject array passed as the sObject[] parameter in the Database method"
Not sure if this means there is an order

Comment: SF would most like try to insert it in the same order, but any failure re-try or any related record locking might cause the disruption in the order of DML. The statement from SF means that the List<Sobject> you insert and the List<SaveResult> will be in the same order (i.e., 1st entry from List<Sobject> corresponds to 1st entry of List<SaveResult> and so on...), even if the order in which DML of the SObjects occurs differs.

Comment: yeah, i thought so. Thanks for your time pal, you've been very helpful